# VBA, transferring selected data from 50 Excel workbooks to a single destination Excel workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Loop in folder is work, but don't work loop cells, don't work copy and paste selected data from 50 Excel workbooks to a single destination Excel workbook. I work in Windows Operating System. I have folder with 50 Excel files. I have single destiny Excel file. Data go from folder to 1 single Excel file.

Help, please.

```
Sub Combine()
Dim s As String, MyFiles As String
Dim endd As Integer, startt As Integer
Dim NewWb As Workbook
Dim newS As Worksheet
Dim i As Long

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set NewWb = Workbooks.Add
With NewWb
Set newS = NewWb.Worksheets("Лист1")
End With

endd = i * 10 + 1
startt = endd - 10

MyFiles = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Nezavisimai\Papka2\"
s = Dir(MyFiles & "*.xlsx")
Do While s <> ""

    [a1] = 0
    If Dir = "" Then Exit Sub Else i = 1
    Do
        If Dir = "" Then Exit Do Else i = i + 1
    Loop Until False
    [a1] = i

    With Workbooks.Open(MyFiles & s)

        .Worksheets("Данные").Range("A1:C10").Copy

        .Close SaveChanges:=False
    End With

 newS.Select
 With newS
     .Range("B" & startt & ":D" & endd).Paste
 End With

 s = Dir
Loop

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Questions with code doing this exist on here.

Comment: I notice that you always paste, iteration after iteration, into the same exact range in `newS`. Perhaps you need to increment the range you paste into so it's not overwriting the same target range over and over again? After pasting, try `startt = startt + 10`

Comment: JNevill, Method Copy Paste is not work in first iteration. Only Add workbook, and open first workbook. After pasting in theory:
endd = i * 10 + 1
startt = endd - 10

Comment: Solar Mike, where are questions with code? I don't find. I find it in AutoIT. But I can't install AutoIT .exe into my computer in the office. The corporation has banned the installation of software (.exe)

Comment: Well, I have one on here and I got several answers from the good people on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Combine()

    Const FOLDER = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Nezavisimai\Papka2\"

    Dim wb As Workbook, wbNew As Workbook, wsNew As Worksheet
    Dim filename As String, i As Long, n As Integer, rng As Range
    
    Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet) '1 sheet
    Set wsNew = wbNew.Sheets(1)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    i = 1
    filename = Dir(FOLDER & "*.xlsx")
    Do While filename <> ""
        ' open book and copy range
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FOLDER & filename, False, True) ' no link update, read only
        Set rng = wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1:C10")
        rng.Copy wsNew.Range("B" & i)
        i = i + rng.Rows.Count
        ' close book goto next
        wb.Close False
        n = n + 1
        filename = Dir
    Loop
    ' save combined
    wbNew.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Combined.xlsx"
    wbNew.Close False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox n & " files copied", vbInformation

End Sub
```